# parse line output into table in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file which contains only lines of the form

```
new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003
```

is it possible to parse this output with bash into a form like

```
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
```

to read it then into python?

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/[^0-9,;.]//g;y/;/,/' YourFile
```

1. Remove any non digit, and ,.;
2. Change ; to ,

Comment: Nice.  Can you explain the `y/;/,/` instead of `s/;/,/g`?

Comment: `y` mean transform like TR where `s` is substitute. y works per peer where s take the whole pattern. So `s/12/34/` change any `12`by `34` where `y/12/34/` change any 1 to 3 AND any 2 to 4. y is always for all occurance and a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below sed command if the contents are in the format you mentioned,

```
$ sed 's/^[^(]*(\([^)]*\))\s*;\s*\S*\s*=\s*\(\S\+\)\s*;\s*\S*\s*=\s*\(\S\+\)\s*;\s*\S*\s*=\s*\(\S\+\)$/\1,\2,\3,\4/' file
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
```

Comment: Note your final version (quite similar to mine, by the way) does not need the `/g` in `sed`, because it is executed just once.

Comment: @fedorqui yep , you're right but your grep command will match incorrect numbers also like `99...9`. So i posted this. I'll remove if you insist.

Comment: No, no need to remove the full approach... it was just that last part (piped sed to format output) was quite similar. Regarding my solution, yes, it is right that won't match `99...`, etc, but should be fine for sample numbers are described by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/[^0-9,.][^0-9,.]*/ /g' input
```

for better formatting:

```
 sed 's/[^0-9,.][^0-9,.]*/ /g' input | column -to,
```

*Gives:*

```
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
```

Comment: Post the output of your commands.  I get `7,59 0 876 0 000433344 0 00003`.  So all `.` is gone and only one `,` left.

Comment: @Jotne, ah missed the dots, fixed now

Comment: But it's still not: `7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003`.  This `sed 's/[^0-9,.][^0-9,.]*/ /g;s/ /,/g'` will help some, but gives an extra `,` at the beginning.  Sorry to be picky :)

Comment: @Jotne, thanks again, modified the `column` command to add the commas.

Answer (score 0):

You can `grep` for numbers:

```
$ grep -o '[0-9.]*' file
7
59
0.876
0.000433344
0.00003
```

With the `-o` flag we indicate `grep` just to print the matched results. This way, you have all your values but not the surrounding text.

If you want it comma-separated, pipe to `tr` to replace every new line with comma, and finally to `sed` to replace last comma with a new line:

```
$ grep -o '[0-9.]*' a | tr -s '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$/\n/'
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
```

Comment: what if there is multiple lines in the file ?

Comment: @pomeh it will still work. Test it with dummy data :)

Comment: This does not work for me with multiple lines, I got: `7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003,7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003,[...]`

Comment: @pomeh it is not quite clear what you mean. If you refer to the trailing comma, it is handled by the `sed` at the end.

Comment: Here's what I get: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?7062643b3ef2bece#6NhMunJ1ghW8i9Pmkh5A1bnTANp2aExhzTMuZ5DkAZQ=

Comment: @pomeh well what I now noticed is that the sample input contains for example `7,59`, that I don't know if it has to be split or not, because the desired output is `7,59,...`. Apart from this, do you mean that if multiple lines in sample input, do you mean that comma separated values should be separated by a new line? As it is not clear in the question, I don't see the need to interpret this (or the contrary), so I am leaving it as it is unless the OP states the contrary. Thanks for reviewing, though :)

Comment: Yes that was my point: multiple lines in the output should result in multiple lines in the output. But as you said, this is only *my* interpretation and it may not what @Hein needs.

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk:

```
cat file

new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003
new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003
new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003
new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003
new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003
new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003
new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003

awk -F ' *[=()] *' -v RS=' ; |\n' -v OFS= -v ORS= 'NF{print $2, (NR%4==0)? "\n":","}' file
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
```

Comment: does not work for me, output has a trailing comma in a new line. Also, this does not work with multiple lines.

Comment: @pomeh It does work with multiple lines also. Also what is your awk version? Are you using gnu awk?

Comment: Here is the output I get: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?f63b7353a24b4663#HCWpWvTucETAIW41q9sSSZJ4eLa1nto1YGdKWdh26KE= My awk version ig 3.1.7 running on CentOS 6.5

Comment: The correct link is: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?281368577b1840a9#ks1rNHAQrHorPkj0tobsfD4ugJ56T6gqNUd5HY6K4Qw= (no expires timeout set)

Comment: @pomeh: Thanks for providing input data. Based on that I have edited my awk command. Check my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

also gnu awk with `FPAT`:

```
awk -v FPAT="[0-9.]+" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s%s", $i,(i!=NF?",":"\n")}'
```

test:

```
$ echo "new file (7,59) ; lim = 0.876 ; dim = 0.000433344 ; r_d = 0.00003"|awk -v FPAT="[0-9.]+" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s%s", $i,(i!=NF?",":"\n")}'      
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
```

The `FPAT` could be made better.

Comment: It may be worth to mention that you need `gnu awk 4.00` or newer to use `FPAT`

Answer (score 0):

Many solutions, only perl misisng ;)

```
perl -nlE '$,=",";say m/[\d.]+/g'
```

- set the "list separator" to `,`
- match only numbers (returns a list)
- print the list

or (ofc) @neronlevelu's solution

```
perl -plE 's/[^\d,;.]//g;y/;/,/'
```

- remove anything what isn't an `digit,;.`
- change `;` to ',' (the `y` *transliterates all occurrences of the characters found in the search list with the corresponding character in the replacement list* ) - aka `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r 's/[^0-9.]+/,/g;s/^,//' file
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003

$ awk -F'[^0-9.]+' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1;sub(/^,/,"")} 1' file
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003

$ sed -r 's/[^0-9.,;]+//g;s/;/,/g' file
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003

$ awk -F';' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1;gsub(/[^0-9.,]/,"")} 1' file
7,59,0.876,0.000433344,0.00003
```

Personally I prefer the last 2 as they don't add a comma and then remove it again, which always feels kinda cludgy and error-prone.